# No white border at image

Tags: html, css

My image (full width) is showing borders on the left and right. How can I solve this?

CSS:

```
.image {
height:293px;
width:100%;
float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://glossi-media-us-west.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/media/2e1ca6c4c68d428f9906afdd9bb19a0dNESHim.jpg" class="image">
```

Comment: Are you using normalize.css? https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: according to your code there is no reason these white borders should appear. they must come from the surronding elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAHKz)

```
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
body {
  background: #000;
}
.image {
height:293px;
width:100%;
float: left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any borders, there seems to be no reason why there would be based on the code. Also I don't know the context of the img tag you have but adding a margin:0px; style to body like so

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}
```

removes surrounding white space if that is what you are talking about. That might have more to do with the jsfiddle environment than your problem though.

You could also try the following for debugging purposes to see some other css code is affecting your img element.

```
img{
    border:0 !important;
}
```

If that does not work try use for debugging purposes the following to see if some other code is affecting your img element

```
*{
    border:0 !important;
}
```

Try http://jsfiddle.net/AuroraArcade/w3gx4x7n/2/